# How to read file, convert binary buffer to binary string and later convert the binary string to binary buffer again in python?

Tags: python, file-handling

I opened a file (.jpeg) in binary format and stored it's content in a variable and converted the binary buffer into string using str(). Now, I want to convert the string into binary buffer again.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
file = open(file_path,"rb")
file_content = file.read()
file.close()
print(file_content)
file_content_str = str(file_content)
print(file_content)

# want a code to convert file_content_str into bytes again here
# file_content_bytes = file_content_string converted to bytes

# file2 = open("moon2.jpg", "w+b")
# file2.write(file_content_bytes)
# file2.close()
```

Comment: For the way you converted it to string, "ast.literal_eval" should convert it back.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes it worked, thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity where is "ast.literal_eval"?

Comment: @RufusVS This is short for: module "ast", function "literal_eval". Unlike "eval" it is safe to be used on unknown (potentially malicious) data.

Comment: @MichaelButscher  Thanks!  I will look up the ast module!

Comment: @MichaelBuscher Wow, that ast module is some **_Deep Python!_**.  I really like that particular function though because I always worry about eval...

Answer (score 1):

As much as I avoid eval, try this:

`file_content_bytes = eval(file_content_str)`

Comment: I tried this but there is difference in file_content_str and file_content_bytes

file_content_str = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff..........

file_content_bytes = b'b\'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x00`\\x00`\\x00\\x00\\xff........